# twitter bootstrap: how to add x on the right for clearing inside input box when user is typing?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following search field. I want to add an x  on the right for clearing inside the input search field. The x should show up only when the user enters text or there is some text in the input field. How can i do this?

```
<div class="form-group search-bg">
                            <label class="labelfinder">
                                Finder
                            </label>
                            <button class="btn btn-default push-right1" id="openmodalOnfocus" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                            <label class="sr-only" for="search">Enter search</label>
                            <input type="search" class="form-control border-left-none"  placeholder="Search keyword">

                        </div>
```

Comment: have you tried anything? use bootply.com or jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com and show us the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little snippet with some validation checks (to make it look right):

```
var button_exists = false;

$('input[type=search]').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val()!="" && button_exists==false){
    //this block checks if the user has typed something
    //and if the x button doesn't already exist, when the conditions
    //are true, the button is created
    $(this).before('<span class="input-group-addon"><button type="button" class="close search-clear">&times;</button></span>');
    button_exists = true;
  }
  else if($(this).val()=="" && button_exists==true)
  {
   //if the user has cleared the input and the button exists, 
   //it should be removed
    $(this).prev('span').remove();
    button_exists=false;
  }
});

$(document).on('click','button.search-clear',function(){
  //when the x button is clicked, clear the input and remove the button
  $(this).closest('div').find('input[type=search]').val('');
  $(this).closest('span').remove();
  button_exists=false;
});
```

In the HTML you need to wrap it inside the `.input-group`:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="search" class="form-control border-left-none"  placeholder="Search keyword">
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/b5S2fha1vu)**

Reference:

1) [.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) - event to detect once the user has pressed and released the key

2) [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - to bind the click event for the dynamically created button